# Spree add authentication to every page ... See store after loggin in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, spree

I am using Spree for my new project and my project's requirement is little different. i.e I want users to log in first, upload pic of their stuff - each piece has predefined fix rate - and then checkout and let us know how many pieces they want.

I have installed spree 3-0 stable and basic store is well setup and spree-devise-auth has been setup.

My most important issue is:-

1. Authentication for every page of spree.

Is it a single line solution? like before_filter :!authenticate_user? If so, then where to write it. Can i add it in Spree StoreController? I have searched whole net and i face errors while doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `base_controller` of spree and write `before_filter` method into it.

`base_controller` which inherits `application_controller` so it can pre-execute any `before_filter` action.

override using `base_controller_decorator.class_evel` mechanishm.